# Changing the style of a polygon with a click event in a Shiny/Leaflet app

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

I'm attempting to create my first Shiny app using Leaflet. I'm currently trying to figure out how observers work together to update the map when something is clicked. [Here is the example that I've been working from](https://uasnap.shinyapps.io/ex_leaflet/). In this example (code included in link), each marker changes styles and becomes yellow when clicked on, shown below:

[image]

Similarly, in my app, I want my polygons to change styles when they are clicked. **While the example is very useful, I'm having problems translating the code from marker clicks to shape clicks.**

Here is some example code with my [shapefiles available for download here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dndauznctn1s31t/AABroXe9LQKFkHzq7iTp1KJja?dl=0).

```
library(shiny)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)

ctry <- readOGR("D:/", layer = "ctry", stringsAsFactors = F)


shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(leafletOutput("map")),

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(ctry) %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addPolygons(fillColor = "gray", 
                    fillOpacity = 1, 
                    weight = 2, 
                    stroke = T, 
                    color = "blue", 
                    opacity = 1)
    })


    observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
      click <- input$map_shape_click
      proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
      if(click$id == "Selected"){
        proxy %>% removeShape(layerId = "Selected")
      } else {
        proxy %>% addPolygons(fillColor = "black", layerId = "Selected")
      }
    })


  })
```

This code pretty closely follows the linked example with an attempt to work with shapes instead of markers. When I run the code, however, I get the following error:

> Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero Stack trace
>   (innermost first):
>       68: observeEventHandler [#22]
>        4: 
>        3: do.call
>        2: print.shiny.appobj
>        1:  ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

I'm not sure where to go from here. Again, I want to change the style of my polygons whenever they are clicked (in the example, I made the fill black). What am I doing wrong?

---

I've continued to play around with my code a bit more and I think I have narrowed the problem down to the `if(click$id == "Selected")...` statement. It was my understanding that the click event is what triggered `click$id` to be populated by the string "Selected." However, when I print `click$id` from the example markers, I get the location name. I am really unsure of how this "Selected" id works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is *the* solution, but I found a solution that works for my purpose! It appears that the problem was with my click event. When I clicked on a polygon, the result was still only a point rather than a polygon. I subset my `ctry` object by the click point and set that object as my data in the final `addPolygons()` function. I also added some groups and layerIds.

```
library(shiny)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)

ctry <- readOGR("D:/", layer = "ctry")
proj4string(ctry) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(leafletOutput("map")),

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addPolygons(data = ctry, 
                    fillColor = "gray", 
                    fillOpacity = 1, 
                    weight = 2, 
                    stroke = T, 
                    color = "blue", 
                    opacity = 1,
                    group = "Countries", 
                    layerId = ~admin)
    })

    observeEvent(input$map_shape_click, {
      click <- input$map_shape_click

      if(is.null(click))
        return()   

      #pulls lat and lon from shiny click event
      lat <- click$lat
      lon <- click$lng

      #puts lat and lon for click point into its own data frame
      coords <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon, lat))

      #converts click point coordinate data frame into SP object, sets CRS
      point <- SpatialPoints(coords)
      proj4string(point) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

      #retrieves country in which the click point resides, set CRS for country
      selected <- ctry[point,]
      proj4string(selected) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

      proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
      if(click$id == "Selected"){
        proxy %>% removeShape(layerId = "Selected")
      } else {
        proxy %>% addPolygons(data = selected, 
                              fillColor = "black",
                              fillOpacity = 1, 
                              color = "red",
                              weight = 3, 
                              stroke = T,
                              layerId = "Selected")
      } 
    })
  })
```